# R Function for setting time intervals in y axis

Tags: r

My dataset is as shown below:

![enter image description here][1]

My R code which I've used is as follows:

library(ggplot2)

dataset <- tibble::tribble(
~flights, ~attribute,                  ~Value,
"Emirates",      "ETA",       "12:30:00",
"Emirates", "Arr Time", "14:50:00 PM",
"Turkish Airlines",      "ETA", "17:30:00 PM",
"Turkish Airlines", "Arr Time", "18:50:00 PM",
"Cathay Pacific",      "ETA", "19:30:00 PM",
"Cathay Pacific", "Arr Time", "14:50:00 PM",
"Qatar Airways",      "ETA", "20:30:00 PM",
"Qatar Airways", "Arr Time", "20:50:00 PM",
"Lefthansa",      "ETA",       "12:30:00",
"Lefthansa", "Arr Time",       "13:50:00"
)

c1_graph <- ggplot(dataset, aes(flights,Value, fill= attribute)) +
geom_col(width=0.4, position=position_dodge(width=0.5)) +

coord_flip()
c1_graph

As you can see from the image, I dont need all datetime intervals in y axis.
I would like to display 13:50:00, 17:30:00 and 19:30:00.

Appreciate help with the R code to obtain this.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Images are not the right way to share data/code.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: library(ggplot2)
dataset <- tibble::tribble(
  ~flights, ~attribute,                  ~Value,
  "Emirates",      "ETA",       "12:30:00",
  "Emirates", "Arr Time", "14:50:00 PM",
  "Turkish Airlines",      "ETA", "17:30:00 PM",
  "Turkish Airlines", "Arr Time", "18:50:00 PM",
   "Qatar Airways",      "ETA", "20:30:00 PM",
  "Qatar Airways", "Arr Time", "20:50:00 PM",

) 

c1_graph <- ggplot(dataset, aes(flights,Value, fill= attribute)) +
  geom_col(width=0.4, position=position_dodge(width=0.5)) +
  
  coord_flip()
c1_graph

Answer (score 0):

You could try using  `scale_y_datetime(breaks = c('Date1','Date2',...))` to set the break points i.e ticks on the y axis to the set dates you want.